# Error updating column in MySQL when using another table as reference

Tags: mysql, date, subquery

Update `period_id` column assigning as value of each record the corresponding `id` when using `created_at` and the `periods` table.

Table `category`

| id | type | period_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | 2020-03-10 21:23:07 |
| 2 | 1 |  | 2020-03-12 21:23:07 |
| 3 | 2 |  | 2020-05-20 21:23:07 |
| 4 | 2 |  | 2020-05-24 21:23:07 |

Table `periods`

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202003 |
| 2 | 202004 |
| 3 | 202005 |
| 4 | 202006 |

I tried

```
UPDATE category SET period_id = (SELECT id FROM periods WHERE Name = (SELECT date_format(`created_at`, '%Y%m') FROM category)) WHERE type = 1
OR type = 2;
```

But I get an error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

The result has to be

| id | type | period_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020-03-10 21:23:07 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2020-03-12 21:23:07 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2020-05-20 21:23:07 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2020-05-24 21:23:07 |

How can I correct the sentence above to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [multiple-table UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) syntax

```
UPDATE category c
JOIN periods p ON DATE_FORMAT(c.created_at, '%Y%m') = p.Name
SET c.period_id = p.id
```

Comment: This is a very clever use of `DATE_FORMAT` +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would store proper dates in your `periods` table, using the first of the month to represent a date:

```
id | Name
1  | 2020-03-01
2  | 2020-04-01
3  | 2020-05-01
4  | 2020-06-01
```

Then, continue with your current approach:

```sql
UPDATE category c
SET period_id = (SELECT id FROM periods p
                 WHERE c.created_at >= p.Name AND
                       c.created_at < p.Name + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

The advantage of this approach is that the above query is *sargable*, and could benefit from adding the following index to `periods`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON periods (Name);
```

With this index in place the lookup subquery for the update should be reasonably fast.